# How good is a forecast? (Many outputs)

Tags: econometrics, forecasting

I have several macroeconomic models (eg two DSGEs and a VAR). They each produce forecasts for GDP, inflation and unemployment, and I have data to test them on, going back years.

**How can I say which model has the "best" overall performance?**

I realise this is vague, so here's more detail:

Assume that model X performs better than model Y on GDP, but worse on inflation.

If I'm just looking at GDP, I could just ask something like "which model has the smallest mean square error?" (predicted GDP - actual GDP, squared)
Similarly, if I only care about inflation, I could do the same thing.

But I actually care about forecast accuracy over all three variables (GDP/inf/unemployment).

**Is there a way to assess accuracy over all three variables, without just assigning weights to each MSE value and adding them up?**

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The MSE is essentially a squared Euclidean distance between two vectors, say $\mathbf y$ and $\hat{\mathbf y}$, where $\mathbf y$ is the actual economic data over $T$ periods and $\hat{\mathbf{y}}$ the predicted values. A natural extension of this to matrices $\mathbf Y=(y_{it})$ and $\widehat{\mathbf Y}=(\hat y_{it})$ where $i=1,\dots,n$ and $t=1,\dots,T$ ($n$ variables over $T$ periods) would be
\begin{equation}
\text{MSE}^*=\frac{1}{nT}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{t=1}^T(y_{it}-\hat y_{it})^2.
\end{equation}

But beware of the [pitfall](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/99171/61402). Of course there are other [matrix norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm) available as well.

Comment: Thanks for multivariate MSE info.

However, the "units" are different for each dimension (eg GDP in dollars, inflation in %, unemployment could be % or absolute). Doesn't that mean I need to somehow "normalise" the values first, to make MSE a good measure?

A simple example: if I measure GDP in $, model Y (great at inflation, ok at GDP) might have a lower overall MSE than model X (slightly better at GDP, much worse on inflation). But if I measure GDP in cents (or Yen, if in Japan), any gap in GDP becomes dominant, and model X suddenly looks *way* better than Y.

Isn't this a big issue?

Comment: @Mich55: Unit differences are indeed an issue that I overlooked. Normalization would seem sensible but it's not obvious how it should be done. A search in the model evaluation literature (e.g. [this paper](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.461.5460&rep=rep1&type=pdf)) may be helpful.